# python ввод ключа и значения ключа через консоль

Tags: python

мне кто-то может объяснить я гуглю а мне выдает одни и те же коды которые вообще не в тему, в питоне есть тип данных словарь мне надо сделать так чтобы пользователь через инпут вводил данные для ключа и значения ключа, как бы я ни пытался у меня получается ввести только значения ключа код в питоне выглядит примерно так
dict_['age'] = input("Enter ur age: ")
то есть в этом коде я уже задал название ключа, то есть age а после знака = вводится значение ключа но я хочу чтобы пользователь задал ключ через консоль

Comment: `key = input('Key ')` потом `_dict[key] = input('value ')`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, чот я дурак :0